# Is there a way to create multiple pages using macro in an opensource software?

Tags: macros, prestashop

hmm it might be very complicated to achieve this. But I just would like to know if I can save time creating pages and uploading images into opensource software (PrestaShop)? I need to design a template for standard page. Then under create page option ,simply use macro to create instead of I doing them manually. same goes to uploading images but no template for them of course. Thanks in advance for any sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create SQL `INSERT INTO` statements programatically that insert content directly to the database.

You can use the [uploadFile](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/upload-file.html) method of [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to automate image uploads.